# VHDL error "Process clocking is too complex."

Tags: vhdl

Hello everyone I recently started coding in VHDL(code here is of T flip flop) and I'm having an error which says "Process clocking is too complex", and this is with the first code attached below and surprisingly I the solution too. But I don't know how it worked, code without error is Second code. I googled about the error for half hour but couldn't find the satisfying reason. Please help.

**First code:**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY t_ff IS
    PORT(t,clk,rst:IN STD_LOGIC;
         q,q_bar:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END t_ff;

ARCHITECTURE t_ff OF t_ff IS
SIGNAL temp: STD_LOGIC;
BEGIN
    PROCESS(clk,rst)
    BEGIN
        IF(clk='1' AND clk'event)THEN
            IF(t='1')THEN temp<= NOT temp;
            END IF;
        ELSIF(rst='1')THEN temp<='0';
        END IF;
        q<= temp;
        q_bar<= NOT temp;
    END PROCESS;
END t_ff;
```

**Second code:**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY t_ff IS
    PORT(t,clk,rst:IN STD_LOGIC;
         q,q_bar:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END t_ff;

ARCHITECTURE t_ff OF t_ff IS
SIGNAL temp: STD_LOGIC;
BEGIN
    PROCESS(clk,rst)
    BEGIN
        IF(rst='1')THEN temp<='0';
        ELSIF(clk='1' AND clk'event)THEN
            IF(t='1')THEN temp<= NOT temp;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        q<= temp;
        q_bar<= NOT temp;
    END PROCESS;
END t_ff;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is quite simple. But first we need to change your code:

Neither version describes the behaviour of a T flip-flop; both describe the behaviour of at least 2, if not 3 flip-flops. This is because

> every signal assignment in a clocked process infers a flip-flop

There are 3 signal assignments in each process - to `temp`, `q` and `q_bar` - so you will get 3 flip-flops (though 1 is redundant and so may be optimised away by your synthesiser). So, first, if you want to guarantee that you only have one flip-flop, you need to rewrite each process so that there is only one signal assignment contained within it.

There's no point in re-writing the first process, because it's wrong for other reasons - see later. The second process should be rewritten to something like this:

```
PROCESS(clk,rst)
BEGIN
    IF (rst='1') THEN temp<='0';
    ELSIF (clk='1' AND clk'event) THEN
        IF (t='1') THEN temp <= NOT temp;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

q <= temp;
q_bar <= NOT temp;
```

In other words, you need to move the assignments to `q` and `q_bar` outside the process. This new version of your second version describes the behaviour of a T-type flip-flop with an asynchronous reset:

> if the reset is asserted then reset the flip-flop; otherwise, if the T
>   input is asserted at the rising edge of the clock, then invert the
>   flip-flop

Had I rewritten your first version, it would describe the behaviour of some electronic component that doesn't exist, so it would not be able to be synthesised. There is no such flip-flop with this behaviour:

> if the T
>   input is asserted at the rising edge of the clock, then invert the
>   flip-flop; otherwise, if the reset is asserted then reset the flip-flop

You could have described a T type flip-flop with a *synchronous* reset:

> at the rising edge of the clock: if the reset is asserted then reset
>   the flip-flop, otherwise, if the T input is asserted at the rising
>   edge of the clock, then invert the flip-flop

like this

```
PROCESS(clk)
BEGIN
    IF (clk='1' AND clk'event) THEN
        IF (rst='1') THEN temp<='0';
        ELSIF (t='1') THEN temp <= NOT temp;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

q <= temp;
q_bar <= NOT temp;
```

Finally, you are using a rather old-fashioned coding style. I would recommend the use of the `rising_edge` function. Also your brackets are redundant. An experienced VHDL code would write your second version like this:

```
PROCESS(clk,rst)
BEGIN
    IF rst='1' THEN temp<='0';
    ELSIF rising_edge(clk) THEN
        IF t='1' THEN temp<= NOT temp;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;    

q <= temp;
q_bar <= NOT temp;
```

Comment: I have 4 points on which I'm not still clear. 1 In first code you wrote `q <= q` so I need to define it as INOUT. 2 Why I can't write `clk='1' and clk'event` is it because of hardware(FPGA) lacking that capability. 3 How can I know how much flip flops I have used in design? I'm using Altera Max+plus II. 4 Why I can't write async. reset after checking t input.

Comment: @rockingsharma 1) use either vhdl2008 settings, as this supports output reading, or else you should use a temporary intermediate signal. 2) `rising_edge(clk)` is better. 3) your synthesis tool should report this. And you should really switch to quartus II. 4) you cannot use `elsif` after `if rising_edge(clk)` that's just bad code structure.

Comment: @rockingsharma 1) you're right (unless you use VHDL 2008 as J.H.Bonarius said). I have rewritten my answer assuming you're not. You needed to move the assignments to `q` and `q_bar` out of the process. 2 & 3) see above 4) I answered that above. If you write you're asynchronous reset after the test for the rising edge of the clock, you are modelling the behaviour of a non-existent flip-flop. The asynchronous reset input of a real flip-flop takes priority: if you hold a real flip-flop in reset its output sticks at reset. End of. You can only clock it if you're not reseting it.